# protocolos HTTP

Tags: c#, web-service, http, http-request

Sou novato na área de desenvolvimento e estou aprendendo a fazer um web service

abaixo esta meus método de consulta, inserção e remoção.
eles já estão funcionando, porém queria saber como faco para passar no codigo qual metodo usar.

Att

ex: metodo consultar uando "GET"
    metodo inserir usando "POST"
    metodo Delete usando "DELETE"
    metodo atualizar usando "PUT"

```
[WebMethod]
public string ConsultarSensor()
{
   NegSensores regrasSen = new NegSensores();
   List<SEN> colecao = new List<SEN>();
   JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

   string jsonSen = string.Empty;

   colecao.AddRange(regrasSen.ConsultarSen(null));
   jsonSen = jss.Serialize(colecao);

   return jsonSen;
}

[WebMethod]
public void InsertSen()
{
   NegSensores regrasSen = new NegSensores();
   regrasSen.InsertSensor("SEN", "Input_20", false, 30, 15, "aaaaaaaaaa", "ouhjflkdfh",1);
}

[WebMethod]
public void DeleteSensor()
{
   NegSensores regrasSen = new NegSensores();
   regrasSen.DeletSen(6);   
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código como texto e aproveite e tire esse `try-ctach` que eles não estão fazendo nada útil, na verdade estão fazendo coisas ruins no código. Uma dica para novatos: Nunca use algo que não entende, primeiro entenda, com profundidade, aí pode usar. Outra sugestão que eu daria e sei que não será seguida. Comece fazer coisas simples, depois que dominar estas vá para as mais complexas.

Comment: "Mas por que colocar o código como texto"? Confira a resposta [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-nÃo-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: @GabrielSilva... Se o serviço é um WS Soap com `WebMethods`, por definição todas as requisições devem ser do tipo `POST`, agora o que você descreve seria o padrão `RESTFUL` e a implementação seria diferente.

Comment: Sim sim, andei dando uma pesquisada e já estou dando uma estudada em RESTFUL

obrigado pelo comentário :)

Comment: Você está usando C# mas não diz se está usando ASP.NET Core, se sim é só colocar as anotações `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]`, `[HttpPut]`, etc